# Cannot take char sequence from String using regex java

Tags: java, regex

for example, i have string "john smith 12 03 1993"
task is to eject john smith to another one.
Now i'm trying to use regex [a-z]*\s*(java validate) but it not works giving just "smith" without john

```
String test = "john smith 11 12323 2323";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]*\\s*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
    matcher.matches();
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Comment: That's because it matches a sequence of letters followed by a space, and you want to match two sequences of letters separated by a space (and maybe followed by a space?)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure it's relevant to use regex here, you would have sooner accomplished your goal by using `String.split(" ")`

Comment: Remember that "john " and "smith " both match your pattern. You may want to print all returned groups to see what's getting matched. If the pattern always starts the line, you could try "^[a-z]*\\s*[a-z]* "

Comment: Also, if you're matching on space explicitly use a space (" ") instead of \s.

Answer (score 1):

You only match 1 chunk of 0+ letters and 0+ whitespaces.

You need to use `matcher.find()` in a while loop and use a regex like `[a-z]+` or `\b[a-z]+\b`:

```
String test = "john smith 11 12323 2323";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
// => john, smith
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/nwnKWR).

If you need to match "words" before whitespace/end of string, use `"\\b[a-z]+(?!\\S)"` regex.

To match `john smith` you may use `"^[a-z]+(?:\\s+[a-z]+)*`" regex (and then you may replace `while` with `if` since you only expect 1 match).

```
String test = "john smith 11 12323 2323";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-z]+(?:\\s+[a-z]+)*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
} // => john smith
```

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/PKaE5B).

Answer (score 1):

```
    String test = "john smith 11 12323 2323";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([a-z]+ [a-z]+).*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
    matcher.matches();
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

`group(0)` is always the entire String (test). Replace `^` with `.*` if the word is not the first thing in "test"

Comment: Note that this matches space " " explicitly. Use \s or \s+ if required.

Answer (score 1):

Java has some tools to make this easier: named groups in particular allow you to write readable regex and extract fields with ease:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Class {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    final String test = "Андрей Парфёнов 05 15 1955";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("" +
      "^(?<name>" +
        "(?<firstName>.+)\\s+" +
        "(?<lastName>.+))\\s+" +
      "(?<date>" +
        "(?<month>\\d{2})\\s+" +
        "(?<day>\\d{2})\\s+" +
        "(?<year>\\d{4}))$");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
    matcher.matches();
    System.out.println(matcher.group("name"));
  }
}
```